# html2canvas - error: Element is not attached to a Document

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I have 2 function.

```
function test() {
    // Get the element.
    var element = document.getElementById('container');

    // Generate the PDF.
    html2pdf().from(element).set({
        margin: 1,
        foreignObjectRendering: true,
        filename: 'test.pdf',
        html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
        jsPDF: {orientation: 'portrait', unit: 'in', format: 'letter', compressPDF: true}
    }).save();
}

$(function() {
    $("#btnSave").click(function() {
        html2canvas($("#container"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And one div

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px; background-color: #1b5c72;">
    <div onclick="doSomething(event, this); changeColor(event, this)"  class="magnet" style="display: inline-block;">
        <object   class="123" style="pointer-events: none"  width="200"
                height="300"
                type="image/svg+xml"
                data="images/tiles/a4-vertical.svg">
        </object>
 </div>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

I can't convert div to canvas in second function and can't make good pdf in first function.  don't appear in canvas and in pdf. I see only empty main div and little red div without svg.
html2canvas  don't work with `<object>`?

Answer (score 1):

So I am not well versed in JQuery since I am a React slave but when I implemented html2canvas in my React app, I had this exact error. I was able to fix this error in 2 ways:

1:

```
const holder = document.createElement("div")
holder.innerHTML=<>My Content</>
//for the following code, you can append it anywhere then just delete it once you're done
document.body.appendChild(holder)
html2canvas(holder).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

2:
if you want to use querySelector or another selector that needs a mounted component then just do something like this

```
<button onClick={()=>{
    const holder=document.querySelector(".my-class")

    //allowTaint:true saves images too
    html2canvas(holder,{allowTaint:true}).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    });
}}>HTML2Canvas</button>
```

Comment: Karl, out of curiosity as I am facing this issue in React (Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document) when using a useRef - how would you implement this in React? (this being the html2canvas)

Comment: @ChristinaStebbins In order to use useRef, you must add it to a component. I also like to use useEffect to ensure that my useRef has been set (it will be null on initialization). Finally, you will need to do ref.current to manipulate and use your useRef. The easiest way for me to do this looks like this:

import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react'
const myRef=useRef()

useEffect(()=>{
    if(myRef.current==null)return

    myRef.current.innerHTML='some text'
    myRef.current.style.color='red'
},[myRef])

return <div ref={myRef} />

If you can, try to read the React docs too.